# Returning value from asynchronous function from within synchronous function in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

I understand that this has been asked before, but the answers provided have simply not answered my question.

I have this synchronous function, numberOfRowsInSection for a UITableView:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var returnValue = 0
    self.getFavorites() { result in
        returnValue = result.count
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

and this is the getFavorites() function:

```
func getFavorites(completionHandler: (([NSString])->())){
    let setter = self.xpcConnection?.remoteObjectProxy as FavoritesProtocol
    setter.getFavorites({(reply) -> Void in
        if var unwrappedReply = reply {
            completionHandler(unwrappedReply)
        }
    })
}
```

Right now the numberOfRowsInSection function returns 0 because the function returns before the async function completes. I understand this concept.

What doesn't help me about the answers that I've found so far is that none of them really say how you can return the value you pass back in with your completionHandler, they all have really easy examples like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    self.getFavorites() { result in
        println("Result count: " \(result.count)")
    }
}
```

That's great, if all you're doing is printing the value, but I need to return the value!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You "can't" return the result of an async block in a synchronous function. I put quotes on 'can't' because there are some tricks you can do to make it work, but you should not do them 99.9% of the time and only if you know EXACTLY what you're doing.

For what you have set up, it's a very common situation, you just need to change your architecture so that your table view is reloaded after you make your async call.

Set a variable:

```
var results: [String] = []
```

In View Did Load, or wherever, call:

```
self.getFavorites() { results in
    self.results = results
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In your counter:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
}
```

Then, in cell for row at index path:

```
cell.textLabel.text = results[indexPath.row]
```